# No-arbitrage framework and the coordinate process

Tags: stochastic-processes, no-arbitrage-theory

In the paper by Beiglböck et al, I encountered the following description of the no-arbitrage framework (see screenshot below). What is the meaning of this coordinate process $S_i$? How does it relate to the usual postulation of The First Fundamental Theorem of Asset Pricing, i.e, that a discrete market on a discrete probability space is arbitrage-free if, and only if, there exists at least one risk-neutral probability measure $\mathbb{Q}$ that is equivalent to the original probability measure $\mathbb{P}$?

[image]